# Is there a way to program a discord bot to send a message or add a reaction whenever a specific person sends a message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm extremely new to coding, but I thought I'd try my hand at making bots in discord to hopefully get some interest in coding while also learning.

Long story short, I'm trying to mess with somebody who hates when I use an emoji by setting a bot to send it or add a reaction whenever they send a message.

I couldn't find a way to do this. I believe I'd have to set a loop to constantly check if they have sent a new message, but even then I can't figure out how to have it detect if someone has spoken.

Currently I have this:

```
@client.event
@commands.check(is_it_me)
async def on_message(message):
    message_text = message.content.strip().lower()
    if "a" in message_text:
        await message.channel.send(":Limji:")
        return
    elif "e" in message_text:
        await message.channel.send(":Limji:")
        return
    elif "i" in message_text:
        await message.channel.send(":Limji:")
        return
```

I planned to do the rest of the vowels, but when testing this the bot would repeat itself five times over and over. This is not an issue when the code only includes an if statement and an life, but I need every vowel and would rather not have the server be spammed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    # Ignore messages from the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:
        print('{0} sent by {1}'.format(message.content, message.author))

    if (message.author.name == 'User'):
        if (message.content.count('a') != 0):
            await message.channel.send(":joy:")
        elif (message.content.count('e') != 0):
            await message.channel.send(':joy:')
        elif (message.content.count('i') != 0):
            await message.channel.send(':joy:')
        elif (message.content.count('o') != 0):
            await message.channel.send(':joy:')
        elif (message.content.count('u') != 0):
            await message.channel.send(':joy:')
        else:
            print('no vowels in message')
    else:
        print('author not recognised')
```

This will respond to literally every message your friend sends in a server with the bot lol. if I was you I'd be a bit more courteous as to add this inside every if/elif:

```py
time.sleep(time_in_int)
```

But I don't get the point of evaluating if the message has vowels in it since most message are bound to have at least one vowel.
Also you dont need to return every path individually, in fact you don't have to return anything at all. Don't worry about performance or anything, it really doesn't make any difference in such a simple case. The returns were not going to make any difference.

Comment: The code seems to have the same issue. The discord bot will reply 5 times and then loop that after a few seconds. The point of the bot is to annoy her temporarily, just so we can all find it amusing and then I could turn it off.

Comment: The code ran as expected for me. Try running this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Dem1se/27be6df0c00d08157c9bc2e9d5cf40cb) and see if the problem persists.

If it is not sending only once, then the problem is elsewhere and not in the code. I'm using py 3.8.1 to run this